# VB.Net - Encode string to hex

Tags: vb.net

this is my code to convert string to hex

```
Function StringToHex(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim xhex As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1
        xhex &= Asc(text.Substring(i, 1)).ToString("x").ToUpper
    Next
    Return xhex
End Function
```

I convert string file to hex with this code, but if size file more than 1MB my program is not responding
how to make this code more efficient for size file more than 1MB sorry my english is bad

Comment: Using `StringBuilder` would help. Right now you're creating a new `xhex` string every time you go through the loop.  That's very inefficient.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, have you tried `text.ToString("x").ToUpper()` and see what happens?

Comment: note error "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Hex Converter.exe"

Comment: on python is like this text.encode("hex"), but how on vb net ? I stuck on this stage :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my initial comment, your current approach is creating a new string each time you go through the For loop.  Strings are immutable (can't be changed) in .NET - so for example if you have 3000 characters in the string, `xHex = &a` is going to create 3,000 strings, and that's just for the first part.  Then you have a `Substring`, then a `ToString` and finally a `ToUpper` - so if my  math is right, you're creating 4 strings for every character in the input string (so if you have 3,000 characters that 12,000 additional strings).

The call to `Substring` is unnecessary - you can treat the string as an array and access each character in the string as an array index, so now you would have:

```
xhex &= Asc(text(i)).ToString("x").ToUpper
```

You can also get rid of the call `.ToUpper()` by using an uppercase "X" in the call to `.ToString()` - so now you have:

```
xhex &= Asc(text(i)).ToString("X")
```

You could also make `xhex` a `StringBuilder`, and then you'd only be creating one additional string each time through the loop (the call to `.ToString()`).  Putting that all together gives you this:

```
Dim xhex As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1
    xhex.Append(Asc(text(i).ToString("X"))
Next

Return xhex.ToString()
```

That may help with the process, but if the string is really large you may still run into memory issues.  IF the file is really large I'd recommend reading it using a `Stream` and processing the `Stream` one byte at a time (or several bytes at time, your choice).

I would also suggest Googling for VB.NET convert string to hex, as there are many examples of other ways to do this.

Comment: some code it's not match but I already fix it...             xhex.Append(Asc(text(i)).ToString("X"))
and         Dim xhex As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Thank you so much :D